# What is the difference between научиться and выучить?

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

What is the difference between научиться and выучить? I understand that they both mean "to learn" but are they used in different contexts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are

**научиться** `+ noun in Dative/verb in infinitive` - to acquire a skill (a set of skills)

**выучить** `+ Accusative` - to learn by heart, to memorize

> Я научился игре / играть на гитаре - I've learned (how) to play guitar
>
> Я выучил названия аккордов - I've learned the names of chords

There's also the verb **выучиться** which is basically synonymous to **научиться** but implies greater effort invested or difficulty experienced, something in the vein of `to manage to learn`.

And **обучиться** (reminded of by Alex_ander in the comment below) which is another synonym with a tendency to connect with nouns rather than with infinitives and having a tinge of thoroughness to its meaning.

On the other end there's the verb **изучить** as a synonym of **выучить** but indicating a more thorough/exhaustive result or a process.
Still in contrast to **изучить**, **выучить** is a bit deficient with respect to imperfective aspect and the present tense as it's almost never used in the corresponding forms, i.e. **выучивал/выучиваю/буду выучивать**.

Comment: _Выучить (кого+чему)_ can have one more meaning: **to teach** someone (typically, a soldier) **by drilling** _with a result_ of giving them a skill in something. "Десять забей, одного _выучи_" - rephrased Suvorov's words.

Comment: @Alex_ander yes, this is a synonym of ***обучить***

Comment: In the same context, "выучить" implies completeness, while "научиться" may mean only a basic skill or knowledge. However, "выучить" usually used in a more narrow context like "выучить урок" ("learn a lesson").