# What is the difference between "изучить" and "учить"?

Tags: грамматика

My Russian teacher tell me that this two verbs учить and изучить means study, but when I need to use учить and when изучить? учить means also learn?

Thanks!

Comment: please also take a look at [**difference between научиться and выучить**](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/17084/what-is-the-difference-between-научиться-and-выучить), as it could be of help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two nuances.
First, "учить" can mean both "study" and "teach".

> Я учу математику (study)
>   Я учу ученика (teach)

Second, "изучить" often has the connotation "to study completely".

> Я учил это очень долго и наконец-то изучил полностью.
>   (I studied this topic for a long time, and eventually had studied it completely)

Answer (score 3):

**Изучить** is also to research. And to learn by heart or learn very well is **выучить**.

> Студент изучил новые слова. - The student has studied new words, he
>   has made a research and come to some conclusions on them.
>
> Студент выучил новые слова. - The student has learned new words, and
>   now he can use them in speech.
>
> Студент учил новые слова. - The student learned new words, or he was
>   learning the new words when sth. happened.

Usually students who haven't learned the words say: "Я учил." - "Вы выучили?" - "Я учил." )))))